# Unknown jsf tag in xhtml page in jsf application

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

This is my first application with eclipse and jsf and i having some problems.

Here is my project structure:

[eclipse project structure](http://postimg.org/image/nb6jxytv5/)

I have downloaded and used JSF 2.1 (Mojarra 2.1.6-FCS) jar file and there is only a single jar file in that and i have used that jar file as a user library.

Now the problem i am facing is that when i use h:head  in my index.xhtml file it shows that h:head is an unkown tag.Of course i am using anugular brackets. besides h:head , i am not able to type that in here.

here is my index.xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <h:head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
   <title>Insert title here</title>
  </h:head>
  <body>

  </body>
  </html>
```

What is wrong here? IS there only one jar file file to be included?

also there are some white packages marks in the jar file i included...here they are:
[while package in jar](http://postimg.org/image/ljvym31gt/)
what does it mean?

Comment: Please use JSF 1.2 or JSF 2 tag for your questions, not both at the same time. The differences between these versions is too broad, and now more with the new JSF 2.2.

Comment: ok i will take care of it from next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't defined the `h` prefix anywhere in your file. If you follow a JSF 2 tutorial, you will note this in the `<html>` tag definition (this one is taken from [StackOverflow JSF wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)):

```
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
```

Where

- `h` for JSF HTML tags like `<h:head>`, `<h:body>`, `<h:inputText>`, etc.
- `f` is the prefix for JSF core like `<f:view>`, `<f:selectItems>`, `<f:ajax>`, etc.